# splitting and merging two files in linux

Tags: linux

My first question is how to split two files like

big.zip.1 
big.zip.2

then, my second is how to merge them like windows

in windows, i can use copy /b

in linux,

cat big.zip.1 > big.zip 
cat big.zip.2 >> big.zip

?

Answer (score 3):

```
split bigfile bigfilepiece
cat bigfilepiece* > bigfile
```